# Create a File and Save in BaseAdapter file Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, data-binding

Basically, I have a Local DB file called DBhelper in which i have this function

```
public void addWallpost(Wall accountwallpost) {
    Log.d("addWallPost", accountwallpost.toString());

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_WALL_ID, accountwallpost.wallID);
    values.put(KEY_WALL_POSTER, (accountwallpost.poster).toString());
    values.put(KEY_WALL_POST, accountwallpost.wallContent);
    values.put(KEY_WALL_POSTER_COMPANY_ANNOUNCE_TITLE, accountwallpost.announcementTitle);
    values.put(KEY_WALL_POSTER_COMPANY_ANNOUNCE_LINK, accountwallpost.announcementLink);
    values.put(KEY_WALL_TARGET_NAME, (accountwallpost.target).toString());
    values.put(KEY_WALL_NUMBER_LIKES, accountwallpost.userLike);
    values.put(KEY_WALL_GAP, accountwallpost.gap);

    db.insert(TABLE_ACCOUNTWALLPOST, null, values);
    db.close();

}
```

I have this other file which loads from the server database all the values of the Wallpost table

```
public List<Wall> loadHome(long accountID, int start, int numberOfResult) throws Exception {
        this.setFunction("LOAD_HOME");
        this.addAccountID(accountID);
        this.addParameter("start", start);
        this.addParameter("numberOfResult", numberOfResult);


        return WallParser.parseWallList(this.postJSON().getJSONArray("wallpost"));
    }
```

What i need help in is how do i save the data from the server database to the Local DB?

I tried adding the code

```
DBHelper.get(context).addWallpost(accountwallpost);
```

But i dont know how to get a row from the server database since the data is gotten as a List.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why do you want to save the content of the ViewHolder?

Comment: As @blackbelt said, why?  But in any case, `but it is not working` tells us nothing.

Comment: What is a BaseAdapter file?

Comment: made edits to the problem. I hope this clarifies what im planning to do.